# Vuetify select menu is not showing

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify datatables, and when i click the "rows per page" select or an input select, the menu with their options is not showing properly. I mean, it's rendered and loaded, but it doesn't appear in the position it's expected to be, below the input.

I noticed that this was happening because vuetify is absolute positioning this menu element. So i just applied the below css code and it just go okay.

```
--custom_vuetify.scss
/* After load vuetify default styles */

/* Don't put it in an scoped styles, it won't work */
.v-menu {
  /* position: relative; */
}
.v-menu__content {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

I tried on firefox and in another project with different structure, and the same happens. And yes, it also work on their page and codepen, i don't really know why it doesn't in my project.

Here's the examples:

[Without my css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnoGE.png), it shows "opened" and creates a page scroll, obviously because it's calculated positions.

[With my css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egbgw.png) it overflows but at least it's showing

But anyone knows why this happens?
Or if this happens to someone, how do you resolve it?

I'm ok with this solution, but i just want to leave it here just in case someone gets the same problem and wants to show us other posible solutions.

Comment: kindly reproduce for example on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com/)

Comment: I try on https://codesandbox.io/s/xlp2yzxrq and it seems work fine.

Comment: Yes, it works fine on codepen and in their web, i don't know why vuetify doesn't like my project xD
Really, i left only vuetify styles and it goes the same.